# Is the following a noun clause?

Tags: grammar, clauses

Breakfast made me feel sick.

In the sentence, I understand that the subject is breakfast, and the verb is made, but is "made me feel sick" a noun clause or do these all start with wh** words?

Answer (score 1):

"Breakfast" is indeed the subject and "made" is the verb.  However, in this sentence there is an elliptical infinitive phrase (i.e., "to feel sick"), being used as a noun--and indeed the direct object, leaving "me" as the indirect object.  There is no noun clause.

Answer (score 0):

"feel sick" in the sentence above is a predicative adjective over the object "me", "made" is the verb, and "breakfast" is the subject.

A predicative adjective or more generally a predicative expression:

> "serves to express a property that is assigned to a "subject", whereby this subject is usually the clause subject, but at times it can be the clause object"

So it is very similar functionally to complements, ie "I am tired" or "The ball is red".

See this article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression

To answer more specifically your question, "made me feel sick" is not a noun clause or a noun phrase but is actually the predicate.

Comment: Actually, *feel sick* is an infinitive clause whose subject is *me*. Consider the sentence "She made all the noisy childen be quiet."